# Interrogate application using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I used reflection a couple of time to get values from the screen element, call methods etc. But now I am working on an application called Avaya, as this is not a really famous application I cannot find any help. My goal is to get some fields from this application, using automation UI library is not possible as the fields are not visible with any UI inspector like Spy++ and etc..

The only way to solve my issue is to develop a small code that interrogate the application and the result will be what is available for me, each method, each value, etc..

Then I have to start from the interface, I went to regedit and I got a list of 20 interfaces, then I start my code looping at these interfaces to get all classes and after that loop to each methods and proprieties, is that correct? Then I start my code getting a type and creating and instance..:

```
try            {
foreach (string ThisInterface in ArrayInterfaces)
{
ThisInterfacee = ThisInterface;
//Call this interface
Type AvayaWorkspaceType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(ThisInterface, true);
//Create Instance of this
object workspace = Activator.CreateInstance(AvayaWorkspaceType);
```

Any ideas of how to continues??

Thanks a lot any suggestion is welcome :)
I use reflection and C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Reason why I am not able is because Reflection will only work with .NET base application, for other applications you should use IUIautomation or user32.dll